# Where is Express.js' API?

Tags: node.js, express

have known node.js and express several days ago. I feel they are really cool, however, lacking of something.

I looked the official site, but it just point to Connect's API.
But I can't find a document which teach me how to use a simple function such as expressHTTPServer.get().

Of course I read the nodejs's API, but the Express and Connect seems to extend them very much.

For example, in Express official site:

```
app = express.createServer();
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res, next){
   loadUser(req.params.id, function(err, user){
     if (err)
       return next(err);
    res.send('Viewing user of csser.com ' + user.name);  }
   );
});
```

But sadly, no API document talk me there is expressHTTPServer.get and what it's callback arguments are.

I like to read examples, but I really need an API to learn a new language/library/framework, anyone helps?

Comment: [You have read the guide right?](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) Specifically [routing](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) and you've watched the [screencasts](http://expressjs.com/screencasts.html) right?

Comment: Yes, I have. They're eassys, not dictionaries. Of course "only eassys but no dictionary" is better than the other way around. I just think, uh, IF there is a dictionary...

Comment: Hsuan so your complaining about the reading format, the API is pretty clear if you read the guide.

Comment: 100% agree. Where's the API reference???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the official docs: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Also, the source can answer a lot of your questions: https://github.com/visionmedia/express

Comment: I often find myself looking to connect code: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect 

I do know what you mean...there isn't a great single reference for this stuff. I find myself using the docs, examples people list, and most importantly the source.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get to know the API of the req and res parameters passed to your callback, right?

Have a look at [http.ServerRequest](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/http.html#http.ServerRequest) and [http.ServerResponse](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/http.html#http.ServerResponse)

Express itself uses Connect which uses the standard Node.js HTTP API. The arguments passed to your callback are monkey patched instances of the described objects.

The Argument "next" is a function you can call if you wish that the request gets handled by another middleware module. If you want to handle the request within your handler, this doesn't need to bother you.